# nodejs web server and simultaneous file append

Tags: node.js, fs, event-loop

I've read about nodejs event-loop, but what i don't understand well is:

> - i've created a simple http-server that logs the whole request post-data to a file .
> - i used apache-ab to flood it with a 700 kb file for-each request it does .

i imagined that each request will write some chunks after each other each tick in the event-loop, but i found that the full post data is written completely after each request and i don't know why , and i cannot understand it .

---

i'm using something like this

```
stream = require('fs').createWriteStream('path/to/log.file', {flags: 'a'})
log = function(data){
   return stream.write(data)
}

require('http').createServer(function(req, res)
{

   // or req.pipe(stream)
   req.on('data', function(chunk){
     log(chunk.toString() + "\r\n")
   })

   req.on('end', function(){
      res.end("ok")
   })

}).listen(8000)
```

---

sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: post your code. Are you opening file using `fs.appendFile` on each request?

Comment: i added an example, i'm using writeStream

Comment: add append flag: `createWriteStream('path/to/log.file', {flags:'a'})`

Comment: sorry i missed to write it in the code above, but this isn't the problem

Comment: the problem is, i cannot understand why it doesn't write each chunk it reads from each request not the whole data once

Comment: interesting question. perhaps try a larger payload, something on the order of 50 MB? this would mostly eliminate the possibility that the  entire payload is coming in as a single chunk. and/or, you could log some metrics on how large exactly each chunk is

Comment: my payload is a 700 kb of image data and i think the maximum chunk that nodejs uses is about 65535 bytes = 65.535 kb !
so the 700 bytes must be ~ 10.7 chunks ! not just one chunk

Comment: chunking is an HTTP thing, not a node.js thing; there's no max size and the size of each chunk is determined by the sender. i'd say it's time to put on the labcoat and try some experiments :)

Comment: thanks everyone, i've found that stream.write was returning false, so i used drain event and the result is what i want, thanks for your time ^_^
i've posted the issue and its solution as an answer .

Answer (score 2):

I edited the code to output the chunk size and also use an easily identifiable word 'SQUIRREL' to search for in the log file.  I also sent the image file using curl instead of apache ab, mainly because I do not have it setup.

If you look at the output of http in the terminal you are running it, you will see the chunk size for each chunk as it is processed, which in my case was 65536 (as you alluded to in your comments we should see).  In a text search, I see the word SQUIRREL one time for each chunk that was processed.

There is nothing wrong with your code, hopefully making these changes will allow you to see what you are expecting to see.

```
stream = require('fs').createWriteStream('./logfile.txt', {flags: 'a'});
log = function(data){
   return stream.write(data);
};

require('http').createServer(function(req, res)
{

   // or req.pipe(stream)
   req.on('data', function(chunk){
     log(chunk.toString() + "SQUIRREL ");
     console.log(chunk.length);
   })

   req.on('end', function(){
      res.end("ok");
   })

}).listen(8000)
```

curl --data-binary "@IMAG0152.jpg" http://localhost:8000

Comment: i think this is not the real issue, but the problem is when a client enters the server, the server accepts its connection, then it added to the queue, in my server's code it listen `req.on('data', function(chunk){log(chunk.toString())})`
and because of async nature, each request may/should log the chunks,
not waiting each request to end !, i searched for buffer-size but also it is not the problem

Comment: req -> on-data -> log(data) -> and so on for each request

Comment: I suspect Apache AB must not be sending the file in chunks.  I don't see any issues with your code.

Comment: anyway nodejs stream reads any data as chunks, each chunk has a maximum bytes of data , so it isn't the problem of the client "apache ab",
i know that there is no issues in the code, but i want to know why it writes the whole request payload as one chunk !

Comment: thanks @Nimix, i've found that stream.write was returning false, so i used drain event and the result is what i want, thanks for your time ^_^
i've posted the issue and its solution as an answer .

Answer (score 1):

> thanks to everyone tried to help, i found the main issue
>   **the `stream.write` was returning false** i've added the following code to use `drain` event with `.pause()` and `.resume()` and the
>   problem solved

```
ok = stream.write(chunk)

if ( ! ok )
{
    req.pause()
    stream.once('drain', function(){
        req.resume()
        stream.write(chunk)
    })
}
```